# Importing Errors

Tags: python, django

I am getting errors in almost all imports please help.

i'm using django 2.2.5, python 3.7, but getting errors in unresolved import'django.contrib' ,unresolved import'django.urls',unresolved import'django.shortcuts' etc

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
path("", include("hello.urls")),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home(request):
return HttpResponse("Hello, Django!")

Message=No module named 'django'
File "C:\Users\Sharf\Desktop\python projects\p1\calc\urls.py", line 1, 
in <module>
from django.urls import path
```

Comment: from .django.contrib import admin

Comment: @LinPy Why `.` before django? We can import directly.

Comment: depends of the location of your python files ....

Comment: *No module named 'django'* You need to cross-check the environment / installed properly or not from where you are trying to run.

Comment: This happens when you do what? If you're running `python manage.py runserver` or something like that, try `python -m django --version`. If that gives an error, then it means you didn't install/activate your virtual environment correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your settings.py file ? I think the problem comes from here ...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [     
    'mainApp.apps.nameApp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'channels'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'app.urls'
```